# How LUIS pricing works?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am using LUIS in my text-based Bot and now confused with its pricing model. The official documents say that Price for Standard Instance (50 TPS) is $1.50 per 1,000 transactions. So far my understanding of a transaction was "API endpoint hit". But after one month of usage, when I spoke to support team they told me this:
Every second you use LUIS its 50 TPS ( transactions per second) so every 20 seconds of use you are charged $1.50 for text. Every 1000 Transactions is about 20 seconds long.

My questions/doubts are:
- Where I can see which endpoint hit takes how much time? I can only see endpoint hits in LUIS/Azure portals.
- What is the exact meaning of transaction here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you got that answer about 'every second using LUIS is 50 TPS'.

Per the page [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/), the FAQ shows:

**What is a transaction?**

- For text requests, a transaction is an API call with query length up
  to 500 characters.
- For speech requests, a transaction is an utterance
  with query length up to 15 seconds long.

Edit: I think the 50 TPS comes in to play on the *amount* of transactions you are allowed to have per second (before throttling, etc). That does not really relate to cost, except that you get more TPS in standard than you do in the free instance.